# NonUniqueResultException when querying with JOIN FETCH a DTO projection that has onetomany bi association

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I got the following entities:

Order Entity:

```
public class Order {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "order",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cart cart;
```

Cart Entity:

```
public class Cart {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
private Order order;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
```

OrderItem Entity:

```
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
private Cart cart;
```

I am using the following query:

```
return em.createQuery("""
            select new OrderDTO(
               order.id,
               order.cart
            )
            from Order order join fetch order.cart.orderItems
            where order.id = :orderId
            """, OrderDTO.class).setParameter("orderId", orderId).getSingleResult();
```

However I am getting:

```
jakarta.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
```

The 2 referring to Order items that have the same cart_id, not orders (there are no duplicate order ids). However, I am not sure why Hibernate does this since:

```
Order Table:

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+

Cart Table: 

+----------+
| order_id |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+

// Since Cart has @MapsId.

OrderItem table:

+----+---------+
| id | cart_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |
+----+---------+
```

I want hibernate to JOIN FETCH all order items, not only unique results, since they're different order items belonging to the same cart.

I don't believe that the associations are incorrectly configured, perhaps not optimal, but rather there's something missing with the SQL query I'm using, but I don't know what.

I'm trying to use JOIN FETCH because the OneToMany OrderItem collection in Cart is default LAZY, in order to receive the order and the cart and its orderItems loaded at once in the same fetch. (Previously I was using EAGER but that was a mess, it had the N+1 query issue).

If someone could help, I'll greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!

EDIT USEFUL RELEVANT INFORMATION:

If instead I return the Order Entity directly with this query

```
 return em.createQuery("select order from Order order " +
                    "join fetch order.cart as cart join fetch cart.orderItems " +
                    "where order.id = :orderId", Order.class)
            .setParameter("orderId", orderId)
            .getSingleResult();
```

It works and there's no problem. However, if I apply the same SQL query for the OrderDTO like this:

```
return em.createQuery("""
            select new OrderDTO(
               order.id,
               order.cart
            )
            from Order order join fetch order.cart as cart join fetch cart.orderItems
            where order.id = :orderId
            """, OrderDTO.class).setParameter("orderId", orderId).getSingleResult();
```

I get

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [SqmSingularJoin(PizzaApp.api.entity.order.Order(order).cart(cart) : cart)
```

OrderDTO:

```
public record OrderDTO(
        Long id,
        Cart cart
) {
}
```

EDIT 2:
I've also tried using a POJO as a DTO instead of a record and still getting `SemanticException` due to cart missing.

EDIT 3: After removing the fetch directive (since it is not needed when querying DTOs) only leaving join directive, I am back at

```
jakarta.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result
```

Whatever I use

```
return em.createQuery("""
            select new OrderDTO(
               order.id,
               order.cart
            )
            from Order order join order.cart as cart join cart.orderItems
            where order.id = :orderId
            """, OrderDTO.class).setParameter("orderId", orderId).getSingleResult();
```

Or

```
 return em.createQuery("""
                select new OrderDTO(
                   order.id,
                   order.cart
                )
                from Order order join order.cart.orderItems
                where order.id = :orderId
                """, OrderDTO.class).setParameter("orderId", orderId).getSingleResult();
```

LATER EDIT: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/nonuniqueresultexception-when-attempting-to-fetch-bidrectional-onetomany-child-collection-in-a-dto-with-join-fetch/9027

Answer (score 0):

If you run hibernate generated query on your database, you will see 2 rows in the result. The reason why it works when you select `Entity`(Order) is Hibernate mapping 2 rows into 1 Order object with 2 OrderItems based on the entity mapping classes. Hibernate never touch your database and doesn't care about your DTOs whose doesn't have `@Entity`. Hibernate made all decisions based on the way you marked your `Classes` with `@Annotation`s like `@Entity`, `@ManyToOne`.
The simplest solution is just to keep your select with Entity(Ordering) and have a mapper for mapping to OrderingDTO.

Comment: The solution you mention is a workaround, of which I already have one in place. I'm  interested in learning and understanding why hibernate throws `NonUniqueResultException`, why doesn't it just take all the OrderItems whose cart_id match the order id/cart id and fetch them into the OrderItem list inside Cart.

Comment: @lotario I updated my answer, it may not be clear & details. You can search for more info or learn the course to have a deep understanding of it. It's a tough road. I hope it helps.